# PyQt automatically restart the timer to a different number

Tags: python, pyqt

I wrote a simple script that pops up a window and starts a countdown timer. It looks like this:

[image]

When the timer reachers zero, it resets back to 7 seconds (or whatever I set in that variable). I'd like to start the app with a 30 seconds timer, have it count down to zero, reset to 10 seconds, then to 30 again and so on. The utlimate goal is to remind me to do something every 10 minutes or so, but only for a few seconds. So for example, the app will count down from 10 minutes, reach zero, remind me to stretch for 10 seconds, but when those 10 seconds are up, it will reset to 10 minutes again and so forth, until I close the app.

Here is the code I've got so far:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

DURATION_INT = 7
toaster = ToastNotifier()

def secs_to_minsec(secs: int):
    mins = secs // 60
    secs = secs % 60
    minsec = f'{mins:02}:{secs:02}'
    return minsec

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.myTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)

        # App window
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.win = QMainWindow()
        self.win.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.win.setWindowTitle("test")

        # Widgets
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.titleLabel.setText("Welcome to my app")
        self.titleLabel.move(50,20)

        self.timerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.timerLabel.move(50,50)
        self.timerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timerLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt Helvetica")

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.startButton.setText("Start")
        self.startButton.move(50,100)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)

        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.stopButton.setText("Minimize")
        self.stopButton.move(50,130)

        self.update_gui()

        # Show window
        self.win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def startTimer(self):
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT

        self.myTimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTimeout)
        self.myTimer.start(1000)

    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        minsec = secs_to_minsec(self.time_left_int)
        self.timerLabel.setText(minsec)

    # def minimize():
    #     pass

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = App()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm not so sure how to logically do what I'm trying to do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.cycle` to cycle between a series of values indefinitely, then just call `next()` on it inside your timeout code. Each call gets the next value in the cycle:

```
import itertools

TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle([30, 10])  # 30 seconds, 10 seconds

# your other code here

    def startTimer(self):
        self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)

        self.myTimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTimeout)
        self.myTimer.start(1000)

    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. One question though, I'd like to get rid of `DURATION_INT` since I have the inital int thanks to itertools. How do I access the first value I put in `TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle([30, 10])`, i.e 30 seconds?

Comment: You could go with `INITIAL = next(TIME_CYCLER)` but I don't know if this works for you because it consumes the first element of the cycler and puts the "pointer" to the second element. So it might mess up the code that calls `next(TIME_CYCLER)` afterwards. Since we can't ask for the first element of `TIME_CYCLER` (it's a generator object so it doesn't have a "first" value), I'd probably save the `[30, 10]` to a different variable and get the first value that way, e.g. `CYCLE_LIST = [30, 10]; INITIAL = CYCLE_LIST[0]; TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle(CYCLE_LIST)`.